# set only the css style of first adjacent div with a class name

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I set the style of only the first div that has class "bla"? (not the second).

```
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    ....(more div's, unknown how many)
      <div class="bla">
        ....
        <div class="bla">some content</div>
      </div>

    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without further structural requirements, this is not possible. CSS is about rules targetting elements within the structure of the document, and with the code you've shown there's no unique way of targetting it.

Comment: adjacent? like the two .blas are siblings? or one is inside of the other like in the example you provided?

Comment: Will the containing divs (referenced in the "more div's, unknown how many") be without classes as per your example? Or can we not assume this?

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo: like the example (nested)

Comment: @n00dle: you can't assume this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simple workaround for this since you can't do that with any special selector:

```
.bla {
    /* style here, example: */
    background-color: #f00;
}
.bla .bla {
    /* negate the style, example: */
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Not really what I was hoping for, but probably my best bet in css.

Comment: JOPLOmacedo provided a valid answer

Answer (score 2):

***I'm assuming with this answer that by adjacent elements you mean sibling elements. If you were referring to parent-child elements then go with [N1xx1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001870/n1xx1)'s answer. That being said...***

You can't target the first `bla` with css selectors alone. But you can target all the `blas` but the first. So, one possibility is to set the styles you want only on the first `bla` on all `blas`. Then override those styles by targeting all `blas` but the first. Like so:

```
.bla {
   ...styles for the first bla..
}

.bla ~ .bla {
   ...override styles set on first bla that you dont want on the others
}
```

The tilde between the two ".bla"'s is called the general sibling selector. If you've never heard of it, head on over to [css selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
getElementsByClass('bla')[0].style
```

EDIT: JOPLOmacedo provided a CSS only (better) answer

I've also found a way to select for instance the second `<p>` after a `<h1>` tag:

```
h1 + p + p{
 background: red;
}
```

Just thought I'd share that.

Comment: Haha actually the first valid solution to be posted. It's a crappy solution but only because it's a crappy problem, and well it's the only workaround for the issue at hand.

Comment: What's with the down voting of a prefectly fine answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can understand it - a CSS solution is asked, not a JS solution. But like I said, it's the only possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

According to pure css, you can't select according to the ordering of the html elements.  Search the spec (here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).  There is nothing that refers to how many or in what order html elements match the given selectors.